# How to check whether a string is palindrome or not?

Tags: java, variables, scope, palindrome

Im trying to code a palindrome. It has a user input string and the program will tell if it is a palindrome or not. I have searched the net for the code but it seems that when I have created another method, and when compiled the compiler says that "Nullpointerexception". Im trying this since yesterday, but it seems that I can't really understand it. I need it for our ICT class. THank you. this is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {
   String word, reverse="";
   public static void main(String args[]){
       String word;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
       word = in.nextLine();
       Palindrome check = new Palindrome();
       check.palindromeChecker();
   }

   public String palindromeChecker(){
      int length = word.length();

      for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
         reverse = reverse + word.charAt(i);

      if (word.equals(reverse))
         return "Palindrome";
      else
         return "Not a Palindrome";
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error.

Comment: The variable "word" in your static main method hides the instance variable "word" of your Palindrome class. So you are assigning the value from Scanner to the wrong variable.

Comment: Exceptions are thrown at run time. You need to distinguish compile time and runtime errors.

Comment: @Matthias You should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 4):

The variable "word" in your static main method hides the instance variable "word" of your `Palindrome` class.
So you are assigning the value from Scanner to the wrong variable.

To fix this error, you have several options:

The easy way out would be to remove the variable in your main method and redeclare the instance variable of your class `Palindrome` to be static. That however is not very elegant (and not object oriented).
Better would be to pass the value you read as an argument to the method `palindromeChecker`.

There is of course a lot of other ways of doing this, but I am sure you will learn more ways once you get a deeper understanding of this language and programming in general.

Comment: Oh thank you! You really did explain it like how my teacher used to. Haha. I hope so, I'm thinking of taking Computer science after graduating high school. Just sharing. Again, thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. Every question showing a little bit of effort will find people willing to answer on this site.

Answer (score 1):

This is enough to check palindrome

```
 String str="abccba";
   String newStr=new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
   if(str.equals(newStr)){
       System.out.println("is palindrome");
   } else{
       System.out.println("not a palindrome");
   }
```

But still you want to do this in hard way change your code as follows

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String word;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
    word = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(palindromeChecker(word));
}
public static String palindromeChecker(String word){
    int length = word.length();
    String reverse="";
    for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
        reverse = reverse + word.charAt(i);
    if (word.equals(reverse))
        return "Palindrome";
    else
        return "Not a Palindrome";
}
```

Comment: This contains what looks like a working solution, but does not tell the user what he did wrong so he does not make the same mistake again.

Comment: it says that it cannot find the symbol ParseException

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the local variable 'word' in the main method and change the global variable 'word' and 'reverse' to static. But it's better to pass a String parameter in your palindromeChecker method

Answer (score 0):

```
{    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);    
System.out.println("enter the string:");    
String str=s.nextLine().toString();    
   String newStr=new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();    
   if(str.equals(newStr)){    
       System.out.println("is palindrome");    
   } else{    
       System.out.println("not a palindrome");    
   }    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access non-static `String` object inside the palindrome checker. Thats why it show `NULLPointerException`.

You should try the following way:

```
    public class Palindrome
    {
        static String word, reverse="";
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
            word = in.nextLine();
            Palindrome check = new Palindrome();
            System.out.println(check.palindromeChecker());
        }

        public String palindromeChecker()
        {
            String reverse="";
            int length = word.length();

            for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                reverse = reverse + word.charAt(i);

            if (word.equals(reverse))
                return "Palindrome";
            else
                return "Not a Palindrome";

        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package ispolidrom;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class IsPolidrom {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int number;
     Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("\n Enter number: "); 
     number=input.nextInt();

           if(isPolidrome(number)) {
               System.out.printf("\n %d is polidrome",number);
           }

           else {
               System.out.printf("\n %d is NOT polidrome",number);

           }

}

public static boolean isPolidrome(int myNum)  {
    String numStr;
       numStr=Integer.toString(myNum);

    String revNum;
    StringBuffer buffer= new StringBuffer(numStr);
       revNum=buffer.reverse().toString();

    if(numStr.equals(revNum)) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides fixing the variable scope problem. I think the algorithm could be more efficient with the following code,

```
public class Palindrome {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
    String word = keyboard.nextLine();

    if(isPalindrome(word))
        System.out.println(word + " is a Palindrome");
    else
        System.out.println(word + " is not a Palindrome" );


}


public static boolean isPalindrome(String word){
    int length = word.length();
    //loop until i reaches the midpoint index
    for(int i = 0; i < length/2 ; i++){
        //compare first char with last, second with second last
        //and so on until it reaches the mid point
        if(word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(length-i-1))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Palindrome
    {
        static String word, reverse="";
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
            word = in.nextLine();
            Palindrome check = new Palindrome();
            System.out.println(check.palindromeChecker());
        }

    public String palindromeChecker()
    {
        String reverse="";
        int length = word.length();

        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse = reverse + word.charAt(i);

        if (word.equals(reverse))
            return "Palindrome";
        else
            return "Not a Palindrome";

    }
 }
```